# Artinian module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $F$ be a field and $V$ a $F$-vector space with basis $\left\{{v_k}\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}{ }$. Consider the ring $F[X]$ of polynomials over $F$. Let $T:V\rightarrow{V}$ given by $Tv_1=0$, $Tv_i=v_{i-1}$ for $i>1$. Given a structure of $F[X]$-module on $V$ by $(a_0+\cdots+a_nX^n)v = a_0v+\cdots+T^nv$. How to show it's artinian?

Comment: Is $V$ the same thing as $M$?

Comment: Notice that every submodule of $V$ is also an $F$-subspace, and consider a descending chain of submodules.

Comment: If I consider a submodule as an $F-$ vector space, I know that it's artinian if and only if it's finite dimensional, and it's not the case. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry.

Comment: I did not say «consider a submodule as an $F$-vector space» I said, notice that every submodule of $V$ is also an $F$-subspace and consider a descending chain of submodules, which is therefore also a descending chain of subspaces and use what you know.

Comment: Robert, Jim's answer is the point. If you try to do what Mariano is suggesting you will need to prove the hint Jim gives anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that every *proper* submodule is of the form
$$\operatorname{span}_F\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n\}$$
for some *finite* integer $n$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Certainly not, but that it's finite dimensional does.

Comment: Consider the descending chain given by $span_F\left\{{{v_1,v_2,v_3...}}\right\} \subseteq span_F\left\{{{v_2,v_3,v_4...}}\right\}$ and so on. It gives rise to an infinite descending chain that seems not to stop.

Comment: @Robert: $\operatorname{span}_F\{v_2, v_3, \ldots\}$ is not closed under the action of $T$.  So this isn't a descending chain of submodules.

Comment: Uhm.. I'll think about all of this and I'll post later. I'm a bit confused now. Much thanks to all of you for your quick answers.

Comment: @Jim, there are  no infinite integers :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Sometimes people need to be reminded of that :)